# How to add Selenium 2.48.2 in Mozila Firefox 41.0.2?

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I got an error while adding selenium 2.48.2 in latest Mozila Firefox 41.0.2. an error is: " this add-on could not be installed because is appears to be corrupt."
Please solve my problem.

Comment: Perhaps something in the download process is corrupting it. Is this on a corporate network? Are there restrictions on downloading binaries? I would try to download and verify the XPI then drag onto Firefox to install once you're sure it's valid.